# i'm using .net core 3.x (LTS) nuget want to install 5.0, how to make sure it wont install the non-LTS version?

Tags: .net-core, nuget

the project that I am working on must only use LTS release of .net core which is version 3.x

is there a way to make nuget ignore anything above 3.x, right now if I want to update any package, nuget set version 5.0.0 by default which is not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty annoying behaviour by NuGet - logically, it should show you only package updates that are compatible with **your project's version** of .NET Core/Standard/Framework/whatever. Unfortunately, logic doesn't seem to feature in much of the NuGet UI's features.

Thankfully, there is support via explicit [version ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#version-ranges). Say your .csproj contains the following package reference:

```xml
<PackageReference
    Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="3.1.9" />
```

You can force that reference to never allow updating to version 5.0.0 by changing it to the following:

```xml
<PackageReference
    Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="[3.1.9,5.0.0)" />
```

**Unfortunately** (see previous mention of lack of logic in NuGet), should there be a new version of this package (say 3.1.10 - as currently), and you choose to update it, NuGet will discard the range expression and change it back to the specific version:

```xml
<PackageReference
    Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="3.1.10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer my look like the accepted answer, however, I prefer to update the packages in a restricted way manually in order to avoid using non-LTS versions:

```
<PackageReference
    Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="[3.1.10,3.1.10]" />
```

This way of version range will force NuGet to never update a package unless I change the upper limit manually. However, I should rewrite the range after the update.